# in normalization, how to tell if this is in first second or third normal form (1nf,2nf,3nf)

Tags: database, forms, relational-database, normalization

This is an example from class, and for the most part i can turn these into 1NF, 2NF and 3NF. What I don't understand is the question that asks what form is this in to begin with. The instructor didn't explain it and from what I understan, the initial shorthand notation would not be in any normalized form at all. The shorthand notation I am examining is the one in bold. The question that I am having trouble with is the one in bold as well.

**Staff(employeeID,employeeName, salesOffice, officePhone, (customerID, name, address, city, state, zip))**

***Functional Dependencies***

```
employeeId → employeeName, salesOffice, officePhone

salesOffice → officePhone

customerID → name, address, city, state, zip

zip → state, city
```

**What normal form is it currently in? if not in 3NF show 1NF, 2NF, and 3NF**

**1NF**

```
Staff(employeeID,employeeName, salesOffice, officePhone, customerID, name, address, city, state, zip)
```

**2NF**

```
Staff(employeeID,employeeName, salesOffice, officePhone) 

customer(customerID, name, address, city, state, zip) 

saleCust(employeeID, customerID)
```

**3NF**

```
Staff(employeeID,employeeName, salesOffice, officePhone) 

customer(customerID, name, address,zip) 

saleCust(employeeID, customerID) 

zip(city, state,
zip)
```

Would I be correct in stating that the initial shorthand form provided (the one in bold) would be in no normalized form at all?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is totally correct to say that. You don't have to just say it. You have facts to prove as well.

You can write:

As **1NF** states:

**The table must have all atomic values.**

```
Staff(employeeID,employeeName, salesOffice, officePhone, (customerID, name, address, city, state, zip))
```

In the above **Staff** table, **Customer information** is not atomic so it is not in **1NF**.

**Solution in 1NF:**

```
Staff(employeeID,employeeName, salesOffice, officePhone, customerID, name, address, city, state, zip)
```

Then comes the **2NF** which states:

**There should not be any partial dependencies in your table or each non-key attribute must be fully dependent on key attribute value.**

```
Staff(employeeID,employeeName, salesOffice, officePhone, customerID, name, address, city, state, zip)
```

In the above relation, **employeeName**, **salesOffice**, **officePhone** are dependent on **employeeID** while **address**, **city**, **state**, **zip** on **CustomerID**.

**Solution in 2NF:**

```
Staff(employeeID,employeeName, salesOffice, officePhone) 

customer(customerID, name, address, city, state, zip) 

saleCust(employeeID, customerID)
```

And in the last, **3NF** comes which states:

**There should not be any transitive dependencies in your table.**

```
Staff(employeeID,employeeName, salesOffice, officePhone) 

customer(customerID, name, address, city, state, zip) 

saleCust(employeeID, customerID)
```

Now from above relations, **state** and **city** depends on **zip** while **zip** in turn depends on **customerID**.

**Solution in 3NF:**

```
Staff(employeeID,employeeName, salesOffice, officePhone) 

customer(customerID, name, address,zip) 

saleCust(employeeID, customerID) 

zip(city, state,
zip)
```

In this way you will not only say but prove as well that the question was not even in **1NF**.

Comment: thank you i was just getting confused because the way my instructor made it seem was that it should be in some normalized form initially. i just wanted to verify that it in fact was not in any normalized form, thanks a ton.